# Imprimiendo datos recogidos de un modulo

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Estoy intentando imprimir por medio de un for con VueJS siguiendo otro proyecto pero no se muestran los datos.

Este es mi home.vue en la siguiente ruta:
resources/assets/js/users/views/default/control/home.vue

```
<template>
  <main class="main">
    <div class="listing listing--carousel">
      <div class="listing__head">
        <h2 class="listing__title">Trending Movies</h2>
        <a href="/movie/category/trending" class="listing__explore">
          <strong>Explore All</strong>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel">
        <div class="carousel__items" v-for="(item, index) in data.data[rootindex].list" :key="index">
          <div class="card" @mouseover="ACTIVE_SLELECTED_MOVIE(item.id, rootindex )" v-if="data.data[rootindex].type === 'movies'">
            <a href="#" class="card__link">
              <h2 class="card__name">{{item.name}}</h2>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapState } from "vuex";
  
  export default {
    name: "home",

    data() {
      return {
        active_series: null,
        active_movie: null,
        root_index_active: null,
        root_index_show: null,
        show_item: null,
        collection: {
          id: null,
          poster: null,
          name: null,
          type: null,
          rootindex: null,
          index: null
        } 
      };
    },

    computed: mapState({
      data: state => state.home.data,
      loading: state => state.home.home_loading
    }),

    mounted() {
      this.$store.dispatch("GET_HOME_LIST");
    },

    methods: {
      ACTIVE_SLELECTED_SERIES(id, rootindex) {
        this.root_index_active = rootindex;
        this.active_movie = null;
        this.active_series = id;
      },

      ACTIVE_SLELECTED_MOVIE(id, rootindex) {
        this.root_index_active = rootindex;
        this.active_series = null;
        this.active_movie = id;
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

resources/assets/js/users/store/modules/home.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

const module = {
  state: {
    data: [],
    footer: [],
  },
  actions: {
    GET_HOME_LIST({ commit }) {
      axios.get('/api/v1/get/home').then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          const list = response.data.data;
          commit('SET_HOME_LIST', {list});
        }
      });
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_HOME_LIST(state, list) {
        state.data = list.list;
    }
  },
  getters: {}
};
export default module;
```

resources/assets/js/users/store/store.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import home from './modules/home';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  namespaced: true,
  strict: false,
  modules: {
    home
  }
});
```

resources/js/users/app.js:

```
require('../bootstrap');
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueMeta from 'vue-meta';
import store from './store/store';
import Helper from './packages/Helper';
import router from './packages/Routes';

Vue.use(Helper);
Vue.use(VueMeta);

let themeName = Vue.helper.current_theme();
let themePath = require('./views/' + themeName + '/app.vue').default;

new Vue({
  el: '.' + themeName,
  store,
  router,
  render: h => h(themePath)
});
```

Realmente no se que estoy haciendo mal o que me falta por integrar para poder mostrar los datos.
Los datos los recibo en un string en la url que esta en el home.js del modulo home.
Agradeceria mucho su pronta ayuda para solucionar este problema.

Comment: Puedes verificar y compartir qué salida tiene `console.log(response.data)` si lo colocas dentro del `if( response_code==200)` de la peticion. Es probable que los datos no lleguen en el formato esperado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me costo un poco pero faltaba un otro for donde estaba definido el routindex
Code:

```
<div v-for="(item, rootindex) in data.data" :key="rootindex" v-if="item.list.length > 0 ">
    <div class="listing__head">
        <h2 class="listing__title" v-if="data.data[rootindex].type === 'movie'">Movies</h2>
        <h2 class="listing__title" v-if="data.data[rootindex].type === 'series'">Series</h2>
        <a href="#" class="listing__explore">
          <strong>Explore All</strong>
        </a>
  </div>
    <div class="card" v-for="(item, index) in data.data[rootindex].list" :key="index">
        <h2 class="card__name">{{item.name}}</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```